# JSF2.0, value="#" means?

Tags: jsf

I have been trying to write a component control in a `<rich:dataTable>`. I chose `<h:outputLink>` to wrap it, inside the data table. I found something like this.

```
<h:outputLink id="openLink" value="#">
```

What does `value="#"` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a link to the same page. It will refresh the page in a NON-Ajax mode.

---

The outpulink tag produces a very simple HTML  tag with the href value set to the value of the...'value' attribute. In the asker example it will produce:

```
<a id="openLink" href="#">
.
.
.
</a>
```

I added the  tag closure even if the corresponding  was missing in the OP question.